# Grab a string from a list and save it into another list?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to grab a random item from a string list and save that into another string list but I can't get my code to work.

```
    import System.Random
    import Control.Applicative ( (<$>) )

    food = ["meatballs and potoes","veggisoup","lasagna","pasta bolognese","steak and fries","salad","roasted chicken"]
    
    
    randomFood xs = do
              if (length xs - 1 ) > 0 then 
                 [list] <- (fmap (xs!!) $ randomRIO (0, length xs -1))
                 else
                 putStrLn (show([list])
```

I'm getting parse error on input '<-' but I'm sure there are more issues then that. There is also the issue that the list may contain the same dishes two days in a row which is not what I want and I guess I can remove duplicates but that also would remove the number of items in the list which I want to stay the same as the number in the list.

Anyone have a good idea how I could solve this? I have been searching for a day now and I can't find something useful for me but that's just because I'm looking in the wrong places. Any suggestion on how I can do this or where I can find the info will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As I'm fond of telling my students, random isn't the same as fair. Was fair what you wanted? You could use randomRIO repeatedly to take food items out of the potential list into the chosen order list. Alternatively you could generate an infinite list randomly but remove adjacent duplicates. All this is going to take you being a bit more experienced with the syntax, though. Are you reading [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) or similar tutorial? If not, try it out - it's great.

Comment: Did you mean to create a new, random list? Are you printing for debugging purposes? (Or is it just because you want to compile a program to choose your evening meal for you?!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is that you needed *another* `do` after your `if...then`. (After a `then` you need an expression, not a `pattern <- expression`.)

```
randomFood :: String -> IO ()  -- type signature: take a String and do some IO.
randomFood xs = do
          if length xs > 1 then do
             [list] <- (fmap (xs!!) $ randomRIO (0, length xs -1))
             else
             putStrLn (show([list])
```

But that still doesn't compile, because you don't actually do anything with your list.
At the end of every `do` block, you need an expression to return.
I think you meant to still print some stuff if the length of `xs` is too short, and you probably meant to print the selected food if there was more than one to choose from.

Better would be:

```
randomFood :: String -> IO () 
randomFood xs | length xs <= 1 = putStrLn $ show xs
randomFood xs | otherwise = do
             item <- (xs!!) <$> randomRIO (0, length xs -1)
             putStrLn $ show(item)
```

This `| boolean test =` syntax is better for conditional answers based on input.

I changed `[list]` to `item` because you're selecting a single item randomly, not a list of items. 
Haskell is quite happy to let you put `[list]`, because any string that's got one character in it matches `[list]`. 
For example, `"h" = [list]` if `list='h'`, because "h" is short for `['h']`. Any longer string will give you `Pattern match failure`. In particular, all the food you've specified has more than one character, so with this definition `randomFood` would never work! `item` will match anything returned by your `randomRIO` expression, so that's fine.

You imported `<$>` then didn't use it, but it's a nice operator, so I've replaced `fmap f iothing` with `f <$> iothing`.

I finally realised I'm doing the wrong thing with short lists; if I do `randomFood ["lump of cheese"]` I'll get `["lump of cheese"]`, which is inconsistent with `randomFood ["lump of cheese"]` which will give me `"lump of cheese"`. 
I think we should separate the short list from the empty list, which enables us to do more pattern matching and less boolean stuff:

```
randomFood :: String -> IO () 
randomFood []        = putStrLn "--No food listed, sorry.--"
randomFood [oneitem] = putStrLn . show $ oneitem 
randomFood xs = do
         item <- (xs!!) <$> randomRIO (0, length xs -1)
         putStrLn . show $ item
```

This gives three different definitions for `randomFood` depending on what the input looks like.

Here I've also replaced `putStrLn (show (item))` with `putStrLn . show $ item` - compose the functions `show` and `putStrLn` and apply (`$`) that to the `item`.

Answer (score 2):

Few points to note :

- Don't intermix pure and impure code.
- Try to use library for a task rather than repeating what is already written.

Here is the code using random-fu library

```
import Data.Random
import Control.Applicative

food :: [String]
food = ["meatballs and potoes","veggisoup","lasagna","pasta bolognese","steak and fries","salad","roasted chicken"]

randomFood :: [String] -> RVar (Maybe String)
randomFood [] = return Nothing
randomFood xs = Just <$> randomElement xs

main :: IO ()
main = (sample $ randomFood food) >>= print
```

This is like choosing one element from a list randomly.

```
> main 
Just "steak and fries"
> main 
Just "meatballs and potoes"
```

If you want to output just a random permutation of the above list, you can use `shuffle` like

```
main = (sample $ shuffle food) >>= print
```

Example

```
 > main 
 ["meatballs and potoes","lasagna","steak and fries","roasted chicken","salad","pasta bolognese","veggisoup"]
 > main 
 ["roasted chicken","veggisoup","pasta bolognese","lasagna","steak and fries","meatballs and potoes","salad"]
```